# How does one get 996 reputation points with no questions and no answers recorded?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Or, why is my [Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/users/3089/jonathan-leffler) reputation being accounted for so ... weirdly?  Did something break?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your meta reputation is derived from the parent site, i.e., [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/3089)

via [FAQ](https://meta.superuser.com/faq)

> What is reputation?
>
> You must have at least 5 reputation on the parent website to participate on Super User Meta.
>
> **Reputation here is entirely derived from the parent website; your reputation is the same as your reputation on the parent website, synchronized hourly.** Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

Comment: Oh - multiple metas; where's the meta-site for discussing which meta-site should be used for the question?  Too many sites for a poor addled brain like mine to keep track of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that would be [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) - that's where you can ask questions on the Stack Exchange engine in general.

Comment: OK - what happened to Meta StackExchange, which seems more logical...oh, logic has nothing to do with meta-discussions... :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Meta.StackExchange is used for StackExchange v1 sites :) & oh LOL @ ` logic has nothing to do with meta-discussions... :D`